# One page per q Javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a quiz with **one page per question** but i have no idea how to do it.
It's like after answering the first question, you'll proceed to the next (which is on the next page) and then on the final page will display your score.
I know how to make that using radio buttons but i don't know how with **one page per question**.

Using html/javascript BTW.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We don't write code for users here. We help fix code.  That said, I would look into creating a single page and then using JavaScript to hide all questions except the active one.

Comment: You haven't really told us what it is you're wanting to do, what you've tried, what hasn't worked, etc.

Comment: @Robbert thats what i did :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple page that lists every question one after the other. For each question but the first one give the html element the css style `display: none;`. Now when you first load the page you should only see the first question. Everything else is hidden by `display: none`.

Now you just need to figure out how to use javascript to handle a click event for each question that validates whether or not the question was answered. If the click event happens, but the user hasn't input an answer display a message or dialog box telling the user to input an answer. If the user did input an answer then use javascript to add the css style `display: none` to the first question, and remove the same style from the second question.

After you try this out on your own and have some actual code you can come back and ask for more help if you're stuck.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/q29r8bdn/ This might help you get started. Note that it's pretty basic and not necessarily 'best practice' code.